# Chat messages removed by flags are not removed in the recipient's inbox

Tags: feature-request, chat, flags, global-inbox

Today I woke up to a new item in my inbox, a chat reply sprayed with profanity that the community has flagged and deleted.

Could such items be removed from the recipients' inbox as well? Yeah, as a chat moderator I still get to read the message, but it's not something particularly productive or constructive.

Comment: Related feature request that was implemented: [Please clear chat message notifications out of my inbox if the message was deleted as rude/abusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371410/335251) – Since that seems to effectively have been asking for the same thing (though it's specifically about rude/abusive flags and not, say, spam flags), I'm closing this as a duplicate of that post. Feel free to vote to reopen if that's incorrect.